# Create a matrix after gathering data from every algorithm iteration

Tags: r

I have 2 matrixes and based on both I create a second empty matrix named `myDose`. Then I use nested `for` loops in order to calculate `Koff_m1` and `Koff_m2`. Then I multiply those 2 in order to calculate `myDose` which needs to be a matrix or dataframe with all values gathered (after each iteration). The issue is that instead of multiplying `Koff_m1` and `Koff_m2` in my real scenario, I use them as inputs in a more complex function which in combination with every `for` iteration produces a very slow output. This is why I would prefer a solution in which  matrix with the values of `Koff_m1` and `Koff_m2` to be created. Then I could use it to create the `myDose` matrix without the nested `for` loops.

```
Kd1Par<-as.matrix(c(1,2,3))
Kd2Par<-as.matrix(c(1,2,3))

myDose <- matrix(c(0), nrow= length(Kd1Par), ncol = length(Kd2Par))

for (i in 1:length(Kd1Par)){
  for (j in 1:length(Kd2Par)){
    #print(c(Kd1 = Kd1Par[i], Kd2 = Kd2Par[j]))
    Kd1 <- Kd1Par[i]
    Kd2 <- Kd2Par[j]

    Koff_m1 <- 10*Kd1 # (1/day)
    Koff_m2 = 10*Kd2 # (1/day)

    myDose[i,j]<-Koff_m1*Koff_m2
   #print(c(Dose = myDose[i,j]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a case for `outer`

```
myDose <- outer(as.numeric(Kd1Par), as.numeric(Kd2Par), function(x, y) 100 * x * y)
myDose
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  100  200  300
#[2,]  200  400  600
#[3,]  300  600  900
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution in which  matrix with the values of `Koff_m1` and `Koff_m2` would be created first as myDose comes after using them as inputs in a more complex function.

Comment: @firmo23 I don't understand what you mean. You can make the `FUN` argument of `outer` as complex as you like. Or you can multiple `Kd1Par` and `Kd2Par2` by 10 first (which would correspond to `Koff_m1` and `Koff_m2`) and then multiply `outer(10 * as.numeric(Kd1Par), 10 * as.numeric(Kd2Par), function(x, y) x * y)`, which is much of a muchness.

Comment: oh ok I did not know that outer works that way. I was wondering what this function(x,y) was doing at that point.

Comment: Consider `outer(v, w, function(x, y) ...)`; then `function(x, y)` is a function that takes two elements `x` and `y` from the vectors `v` and `w`; `outer` then applies this function to all pairs of values from `v` and `w`.

Comment: Caveat: That only occurs if the function is vectorized over its fist argument (as was the suggested function).